Is it possible to make Microsoft Flow based on an existing flow by simply copy and pasting the flow or saving it under another name?
Is it possible to make Microsoft Flow based on an existing flow by simply copy and pasting the flow or saving it under another name?  I want to make a virtually identical Microsoft Flow with the only difference being the destination Microsoft List that I am using as a database.
This is a short question.  But I think there is not much that needs to be explained.  If you need more clarificiation, please let me know.

Have you tried this yet? It seems like it would be a pretty simple thing to test.
